# Command event not firing asp.net for dynamically created control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the following code that creates an image button dynamically on a li html tag. When I click the image button it does not fire the event. What am I doing wrong please?

Code that generates the control:

```
ImageButton cmdEdit = new ImageButton();
cmdEdit.ImageUrl = "~/Images/phone_book_edit.png";
cmdEdit.ID = "cmdEdit" + recordcount.ToString();
cmdEdit.Attributes["class"] = "liQuestionsLabel2";
cmdEdit.Width = 30;
cmdEdit.CommandName = "Edit";
cmdEdit.CommandArgument = (recordcount - 1).ToString();
cmdEdit.Command += new CommandEventHandler(EditQuestion_Command);
li.Controls.Add(cmdEdit);
```

Event code:

```
protected void EditQuestion_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("here");
}
```

Comment: what is `li` in `li.Controls.Add(cmdEdit);`

Comment: you have to add your dynamic controls again to li on every postback. so if you have placed code of contol generation inside !Page.IsPostback condition then move it outside of condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamically generated controls lose their state after they are rendered. For you to access them again once you postback, you will have to recreate them in the code-behind along with recreating the attached events as well.

Put the above code in your `Page_Load` but not inside the `if(!IsPostback)` so that it gets recreated and you can then access its event.

Other than that, the above code works fine for me when I recreated the same control in my page.